# Can't get stable result with copying random values from array to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, random, discord.js

So I'm in process of creating a bot for a tournament and I got stuck on the part where I want to split players in pairs for play-off-style tournament. I just want to take 2 random players, get them from an array and write it as a value to a key as a round id for an object. Also I should not use those players again in the pair, so need to delete them or smth.
Here's the code:

```
var users = inc.funcs.getDatabase() //Getting a raw array of users (using my func that's basically a simplified fs.readFileSync func)
var tournamentPairs = new Object() //Object initialization

var id = 1
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 2) {
   var first = Math.floor(Math.random() * (users.length + 1)) //Randomizing 2 indexes
   var second = Math.floor(Math.random() * (users.length + 1))

   var player1 = client.users.get(users[first]) //Getting the players by id 
   var player2 = client.users.get(users[second])

   tournamentPairs[id++] = [player1.id, player2.id] //Writing to the object

   users.splice(first, 1) //Deleting user's indexes from the array to not use them anymore.
   users.splice(second, 1)
}
console.log(tournamentPairs)
```

It works perfectly on the outside, but has a bad habit of duplicating users and I once could have a gamergod98 vs gamergod98 for example. I tried `console.log` this crap but it often get an error when trying to `console.log` `player2` because it's `undefined` for some reason. If I try to print `users[second]` I get `undefined` though it never happened for the first player. So I tried different ways to prevent situations like this: `first == second`. Long story short it didn't help much.
I have 9 days 'till tournament starts, any ideas on how to improve this code?

Comment: Your random is using `users.length + 1` so you occasionally get that value, or `users.length`, neither of which are valid indexes in the array. You probably want to look at shuffling the array instead of pulling random indexes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I might have the type of an issue, but I also struggle to avoid reusing randomized values again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `undefined` because you are going out of bounds of your `users` list. For a list of `length` the last element is `list[length-1]`, but you are generating random numbers up to `length`.

To fix duplicate users, remove the first selected user from the list before selecting the second one (or for a less destructive approach, mark already selected users).

```
var id = 1
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 2) {
   var first = Math.floor(Math.random() * users.length)
   var player1 = client.users.get(users[first]) 
   users.splice(first, 1)

   var second = Math.floor(Math.random() * users.length) 
   var player2 = client.users.get(users[second])
   users.splice(second, 1)

   tournamentPairs[id++] = [player1.id, player2.id]
}
```

Comment: I had a code similar to yours, but didn't get the issue with the list's length. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Create a collection of used indexes and then if first or second are in used indexes then continue

```
var usedIndices = [] ;

if (usedIndices.indexOf(first) >= 0 || 
usedIndices.indexOf(second) >= 0) {
continue;
} else { 
usedIndices.push(first);
usedIndices.push(second);
}
```

Put the usedIndices variable before for loop and the if else block inside loop after second